# Hensel's Lemma - Unique in what sense?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, hensels-lemma

> From Wikipedia entry on Hensel's Lemma (paraphrased):
>
> if ${\displaystyle f(r)\equiv 0{\bmod {p^{k}}}\quad {\text{and}}\quad f'(r)\not \equiv 0{\bmod {p}}}$,
>   then there exists an integer s such that
>
> ${\displaystyle f(s)\equiv 0{\bmod {p^{k+m}}}\quad {\text{and}}\quad r\equiv s{\bmod {p^{k}}}.}$
>   Furthermore, this s is **UNIQUE** ${\bmod {p^{k+m}}}$.

Ultimate question: What does **UNIQUE** mean here?
I keep finding seemingly contradictory examples:

> ${\text{Find all x satisfying: } x^2-1 \equiv 0 \bmod 4}$

We find only 1 works (mod 2), and all requirements for the lemma are met:
${f(1) \equiv 0 \bmod 2} \quad and \quad f'(1)\not \equiv 0 \bmod 2$

However, against my expectation, the next iteration doesn't give a **UNIQUE** result mod 4, because the next binary digit may be either 1 or 0, resulting in multiple solutions, specifically it has a mod 4 solution set of {1,3}. It seems to be **NOT-UNIQUE** for that reason. In what sense is the result **UNIQUE**?

NOTE: I'm aware {1,3} = {1,-1} because ($3 \equiv -1\bmod4$).

Comment: The hypotheses are not satisfied since $f'(1)\equiv 0 \mod 2$.

Comment: When $f(x)=x^2-1$, then $f'(x)=2x$ and so $f'(1)\equiv0\pmod 2$. Therefore Hensel is not applicable.